# ef core 3 OwnsOne, Select failed with two Tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The following example fails.

> System.NullReferenceException: “Object reference not set to an instance of an object.”

The saving of the data works. If I get the data with Include, that works too. Only when reading the data then occurs this error. Everything works great with one Table. In version 2.6, the example works without problems.

Can someone help me?

I work with `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.0.0-preview6.19304.10`

Thanks

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class JgLogDb : DbContext
    {
        public string SqlVerbindung = @"Data Source=.\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog = JgTest; Integrated Security = True";

        public DbSet<TabTest1> TabTest1Set { set; get; }
        public DbSet<TabTest2> TabTest2Set { set; get; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<TabTest1>().OwnsOne(p => p.MTest);
            modelBuilder.Entity<TabTest2>().OwnsOne(p => p.MTest);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(SqlVerbindung);
        }
    }

    public class TabTest1
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
        public string Feld1 { get; set; }
        public MeinTest MTest { get; set; }
    }

    public class TabTest2
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
        public string Fel2 { get; set; }
        public MeinTest MTest { get; set; }
    }

    [Owned]
    public class MeinTest
    {
        public string FeldTest { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            using (var db = new JgLogDb())
            {
                await db.TabTest1Set.AddAsync(new TabTest1()
                {
                    Feld1 = "Hallo",
                    MTest = new MeinTest()
                    {
                        FeldTest = "Ballo"
                    }
                });
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            using (var db = new JgLogDb())
            {
                var liste = await db.TabTest1Set
                    .Select(s => new
                    {
                        f1 = s.Feld1,
                        f2 = s.MTest.FeldTest
                    }).ToListAsync();

                foreach (var ds in liste)
                    Console.WriteLine($"{ds.f1}  {ds.f2}");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue might be related to this EF Core issue: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13546

Apparently, there is an open bug in EF Core where if you use projection (`.Select`), it doesn't include the owned entities automatically.

The workaround would be to explicitly include it: `.Include(x => x.MTest)`

Comment: Ah, that'd also explain why I didn't see the issue with Sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the code to use Sqlite, which is typically more limited than SqlServer:

```cs
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class JgLogDb : DbContext
    {

[...]

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=test.db");
        }
    }

[...]

    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            using (var db = new JgLogDb())
            {
                db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                db.Database.EnsureCreated();
                await db.TabTest1Set.AddAsync(new TabTest1()
                {
                    Feld1 = "Hallo",
                    MTest = new MeinTest()
                    {
                        FeldTest = "Ballo"
                    }
                });
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

[...]
        }
    }
}
```

Note, my code is trashing the database (via `EnsureDeleted()`) and recreating it from scratch (via `EnsureCreated()`), so it may be that your existing `SqlExpress` database differs from the model.

That said, I've had similar issues with nested `[Owned]` objects.  It may be worth checking out the [Fluent API for `.ToTable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/tables) as there are currently some limitations to owned entities: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt846463.aspx